# QGIS labels missing when creating XYZ-tiles and using "offset from point"

Tags: labeling, xyz-tiles, missing-data

I have an issue with some of my labels missing when I generate XYZ tiles in QGIS.
I have tested a lot and it seems like they disappear when I use the label placement function "offset from point" under placement.

If I take the exact same map and turn this back to "Around point" all the labels are generated.

I have also tried to adjust the priority and obstacles functions, but it doesn't change anything. So I feel pretty sure that the issue comes from the "Offset from point" label placement function.

I used QGIS 3.30 and I tried to install QGIS 3.34.2 and generated the exact same map. 3.34.2 creates af few more of the missing labels. But still some are missing.

Has anyone had the same problem and found a solution?

[image: left: label placement set to "around point". Right: Label placement set to "offset from point"]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Raster tools > Generate XYZ tile (Directory). All the labels were missing, all the time, from all vector tile service connections layers.
And then I tried the QTiles plugin. And seems it works. Rendering 150,000 tiles currently. Seems they have all the labels. Fingers crossed ...